# How to convert Class<T> to Class<List<T>>

Tags: java

I have a simple requirement in java, but not able to see an easy way to do this.

```java
private <T> Class<List<T>> convertToListType(Class<T> classToConvert) {
// What to do here
}
```

What is the simple way to do this?

edit:

To answer how it's going to be used. (i had simplified the original question a bit to just show the problem.)

```java
public class ListResponse<T> {
  private final List<T> results;
}

private <T> Class<ListResponse<T>> convertToListType(Class<T> classToConvert) {
// What to do here
}

private <T> List<T> getList(String url, Class<T> type) {
    var listType = convertToListType(type)
    var response = this.restTemplate.getForEntity(url, listType);
    return response.getBody().getResults();
```

Comment: Not sure how that would be used. Are you sure you don't mean `private static <T> List<T> convertToListType(T classToConvert)`?

Comment: Create a list and add your object there.

Comment: There is no such thing as `Class<List<T>>`.  There is only `Class<List>`.  `List<Object>`, `List<String>`, and `List<Number>` are all the same class.

Comment: not sure why would you need this, but `return (Class<List<T>>)((List<T>)new ArrayList<T>()).getClass()` works

Comment: @IłyaBursov At that point, you could as well use `return (Class<List<T>>)List.class`. Note that `ArrayList.class` is not a `Class<List>`

Comment: @dan1stiscrying yep, your version is better, but it does not compile for me :(

Comment: Though I think it might need to be `Class<List>` instead of `Class<List<T>>` as mentioned by VGR

Comment: How is this private conversion method going to be used?  For example, `static class MyList extends ArrayList<Thing>` provides easy access as `MyList.class`.

Comment: how you want to *convert* the **class** of some type `<T>` to the **class** of a `List<T>` - this would only be possible if `T` is a `List<T>`, but then it must also be a  `List<List<T>>` and a `List<List<List<T>>>` and so on... | actually not sure what is meant by *converting a class*

Comment: Still mystified, but using reflection, you could have something like `private <T> List<T> getList(String url, Class<T> type) throws NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {// 'Stuff', then ...return List.of(type.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance());}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as [VGR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831987/vgr) [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77662505/how-to-convert-classt-to-classlistt?noredirect=1#comment136916363_77662505), there isn't really a concept of a `Class<List<SomeType>>`. There is exactly one `Class` object for `List`. The `Class` object refers to the actual class/interface/enum/record/... but it does not refer to the typed version.

Hence, you may want to consider just using `List`. You are not able to do anything with the type anyways since it's erased at runtime.

```java
Class<List> c = List.class;
//just use c
```

If you really want to have a `Class<List<T>>`, you can use unchecked casts but note that you can have a `Class<List<String>>` and a `Class<List<LocalTime>>` and both would be the same object.
You can get this by first assigning it to a `Class<List<?>>` and then casting it to a `Class<List<T>>` You also don't need the `Class<T>` since Java doesn't differentiate between `Class<List<String>>` and `Class<List<LocalTime>>`:

```java
private <T> Class<List<T>> convertToListType() {
    Class<?> c = List.class;
    return (Class<List<T>>) c;
}
```

There was also the suggestion to use `getClass()`. However, that won't give you a `Class<List<T>>` but a `Class<ArrayList<T>>` (or with a different implementation) and a `Class<ArrayList<T>>` would NOT be a `Class<List<T>>` but instead a `Class<? extends List<T>>` (ignoring the above issue that there is just a `Class<ArrayList<?>>` and not a `Class<List<?>>`) because [generics are invariant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/10871900). Casting a `Class<ArrayList<T>>` to a `Class<List<T>>` would not just be unsafe but it would be incorrect.

If you are ok with having a `Class<? extends List<T>>`, you can create a local class. This even works without any unchecked casts:

```java
private <T> Class<? extends List<T>> convertToListType() {
    abstract class FakeList implements List<T>{}
    return FakeList.class;
}
```

While you can never have an object of `FakeList`, you can get a `Class<FakeList>` using `FakeList.class` and `Class<FakeList>` is a subtype of `Class<? extends List<T>>` because `FakeList` is a subtype of `List<T>` (at least in your method).

Note that even that doesn't solve the "issue" that you have two variables of different types that refer to the same object:

```java
Class<? extends List<String>> stringListClass = convertToListType();
Class<? extends List<Integer>> intListClass = convertToListType();
//System.out.println(stringListClass==intListClass);//Java doesn't even allow that
Object o1 = stringListClass;
Object o2 = intListClass;
System.out.println(o1==o2);//true
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I think i get it now